# How to run n jobs each x time with delayed job gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

My question is how could run x quantities of jobs each n seconds with delayed job gem?

Example

I want send massive newsletter. However when I send #50 ("example") mail, GMail doesn´t send the emails (SPAM) however its contents is a bit different.

So if I send the newsletter by groups of twenty user each 3 minutes perhaps GMail will send the emails correctly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delayed_job` has an option `:run_at`(https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), you can use that to set at what time the job should run. It doesn't guarantee if job would run at that time, but it would surely not run before that.

So, 20 mails/3 minutes = 1 email/9 seconds.

You can do somethings like this:

```
now = Time.now
count = 0
# then for each newsletter schedule it at intervals of 9 secs
users.each do |u|
  WhateverMailer.delay(:run_at => now + count*9).news_letter(u)
  count += 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this type of thing with SimpleWorker, a cloud-based scheduling and background processing service. It offers DelayedJob-like capabilities but without having to manage servers and queues. (I work at Iron.io, makers of SimpleWorker).

You can schedule a job to run every X seconds or schedule multiple jobs to come onto queue at specific times (different priorities have different target run windows). Rather than pre-schedule a lot of jobs though, you'll probably want to have one or more master jobs that run on regular schedules and then queue up one or more slave jobs to send the actual emails (each checking the database to pick up the next set to send).

You can do use the same approach when facing thresholds with fetching data via APIs. Happy to discuss further if you'd like.

Ken